# how to play sound when alertview appears iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, audio, uialertview

i want to play a sound file when alertview appears and plays continuously till user clicks on ok or cancel.how do i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Zoul says, you set-up and play your sound as you call [myAlert show] and cancel the sound in the alert view callback.  Your code will look something like this:

```
  AVAudioPlayer *myPlayer;

  // ...

  // create an alert...

  NSError *error;
  myPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:mySoundFileURL error:&error];
  // handle errors here.
  [myPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];  // repeat forever
  [myPlayer play];
  [myAlert show];

  // ...

  // in alert callback.
  [myPlayer stop];
  [myPlayer release];
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already call the `show` method to display the dialog, why don’t you simply start playing the sound there and stop in the [alert view callback](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIAlertViewDelegate/alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:)? For the sound itself you can use `AVAudioPlayer`.

Comment: how do i continuously play that sound? and manually stop the sound from playing...also tell me that if another sound is already running will it work?